# How to run n async functions and be notified when they all complete?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to execute a variable number of requests in a `for` loop which are all asynchronous. I need to find a way to be notified when all the requests complete (successfully or not) and to collect their results for processing. Is there a feature for this built in or perhaps a third party library for such tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if their is a feature for this, but you could always keep a counter and decrement it on each completion, checking if you've reached zero.

Comment: I don't know much about the iOS runtime so I wasn't sure if this approach would be threadsafe. Is it safe to assume that Alamofire is running all of its operations in a single thread using an event loop and that my callback blocks would not run concurrently?

Comment: You can always create a serial queue, and inside your callback block dispatch that queue to do the decrement.  In that case it doesn't matter how they implement their own threads.

Comment: It seems that the default manager will execute the callback on the main queue, which would make the callback thread safe.

Comment: The counter seems to be working now. If we have any race conditions I'll definitely check out the serial queue feature. Thanks!

Comment: What about NSNotification ? He should just post notification and monitor it adding an observer